# Gomoku AI minmax, alpha-beta pruning evaluation doesn't work entirely as expected

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am writing an "AI" for gomoku (5 in a row) using minmax and alpha-beta pruning. My problem is the evaluation of the board. It doesn't always block my winning moves, and also should block 3 consecutive active cells with 2 open ends (because if not I can win in both directions and he cannot block). And it's also a little slow (i also tried to minimise the amount of moves i search for, by taking only empty cells that have an active neighbour, but it's still a little slow). So here are my 3 evaluation functions:

```
def evaluate_position(self):
    computer_score = self.evaluate_player_score(self.COMPUTER)
    player_score = self.evaluate_player_score(self.PLAYER)

    return computer_score - player_score

def evaluate_player_score(self, player):
    score = 0

    for i in range(self.board_height):
        for j in range(self.board_width):
            if self.__board.element(i, j) == player:
                score += self.evaluate_direction(i, j, player)

    return score

def evaluate_direction(self, row, col, player):
    directions = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)]
    total_score = 0

    for direction in directions:
        player_streak = 0
        opponent_streak = 0
        open_ends = 0

        for k in range(-5, 5):
            i, j = row + k * direction[0], col + k * direction[1]

            if 0 <= i < self.board_height and 0 <= j < self.board_width:
                if self.__board.element(i, j) == player:
                    player_streak += 1
                elif self.__board.element(i, j) == self.__player ^ 1:
                    opponent_streak += 1
                elif self.__board.element(i, j) == self.EMPTY:
                    if k < 0 and player_streak > 0:
                        open_ends += 1
                    elif k > 0 and opponent_streak > 0:
                        open_ends += 1

        if player_streak >= 4 and open_ends == 2:
            total_score += 10000
        elif opponent_streak >= 4:
            total_score += 5000
        elif player_streak == 3 and open_ends == 2:
            total_score += 4000
        elif opponent_streak == 3 and open_ends >= 1:
            total_score += 250
        elif player_streak == 2 and open_ends == 2:
            total_score += 50
        elif opponent_streak == 2 and open_ends >= 1:
            total_score += 25

    return total_score
```

The evaluate_direction really gives me a headache, probably I had a better version of it, but I kept changing little things hoping it would play good moves. (it was still pretty bad then too).